# How to hide status bar and navigation bar in flutter when user clicks on screen or open keyboard?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that is fullscreen  . 
but the problem is when user touches screen the Top Status Bar appears , or When user touches a textfield  , the Bottom Status Bar and Top Status Bar appears .

How can i prevent this problem  .

Here is My Code For Make Flutter App fullscreen :

```
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Output:

[image]

I'm not sure where are you using that call. Here is minimum code reproduction.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Full screen")),
      body: SizedBox.expand(child: FlutterLogo()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly I did this , but android navigation bar wont disappear .

Comment: In which phone did you try this?

Answer (score 3):

For `Textfield` the solution I settled with is to return the user to Full Screen mode (i.e. hide status & navigation) when the Textfield losses focus...

```
class _SomeWidget extends State<SomeWidget> {

    FocusNode _focus = new FocusNode();

    void _onFocusChange(){
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]); // hide status + action buttons
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _focus.addListener(_onFocusChange);
    }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       
       return TextField(
           focusNode: _focus,
           ...
           );
    }
}
```